# WPF XAML Generics Class Binding

Tags: wpf, generics, xaml, binding

Can you bind in XAML to a Class that takes a type T?

If I have a class `myCLASS<T>` and I want to bind a `List<myClass<int>>` to XAML can you do it?

Or do  you have to write a wrapper `class newMyClass: myClass<int>` and then bind the XAML to `newMyClass`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF binding subsystem supports any type of object, structures, classes, generic classes and even dynamic objects.  All that matters is that the instances have **properties**.

You cannot create generic classes in the resources of a typical WPF application because the object creation syntax does not support it.  Nevertheless, objects that are created in code-behind, in your view-model, or by services (even if they are instances of generic types or nested generic types), can still participate in binding.

Here's an example based on the question.  Here's some XAML for a window:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Padding="10">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" , "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Y}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

and here's a generic class that resembles a `Point` class:

```cs
class myClass<T>
{
    public T X { get; set; }
    public T Y { get; set; }
}
```

and here is some code-behind to support the binding in the XAML above:

```cs
void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = new List<myClass<int>>
    {
        new myClass<int> { X = 1, Y = 2 },
        new myClass<int> { X = 3, Y = 4 },
    };
}
```

and this is what it looks like:

[image: Generic Binding]

We created instances of the generic class in the code-behind but **bound to that data** using XAML.

Answer (score 1):

XAML 2009 supports it using `x:TypeArguments`, but it isn't an comfortable option at the moment since it isn't supported by Microsoft's XAML to BAML compiler. For XAML 2009, you would have to read the XAML using `XamlReader` yourself, but then lose greater functionality like a code behind. You're best off doing as you suggested at the moment.